# Highcharts - Area between two y values highlighted

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, area, confidence-interval

I have a situation where I need to predict a trend in a time series, and I have to display confidence intervals.  Is there a way to plot two sets of y-values in Highcharts as linked, and shade the area between the two? Something like this:

http://www.psychosomaticmedicine.org/content/74/4/377/F2.large.jpg

I have five time series: the prediction, two time series that bound the narrower confidence interval, and two more time series that bound the wider confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Beta has that feature:

[see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/WRcj9/light/)

You can read more about the upcoming features [in this post.](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/46-gauges-ranges-and-polar-charts-in-beta)

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts does not natively support range charts (as of version 2.2.5), but there is a workaround. You can stack two area series on top of each other, with the foremost series having a background color matching that of the chart background.

And here is example javascript (that results in [this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/range.htm)):

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container', 
            defaultSeriesType: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Range chart emulation'
        },
        xAxis: {
        },
        yAxis: {    
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            // this series defines the height of the range
            name: 'Range',
            data: [1,2,3,5,7,8,9,6,4,7,5,3,4,7,6,5,6,7,5,4,2]
        }, {
            // this series defines the bottom values
            name: 'Dummy',
            data: [0,1,2,3,3.5,7,8.5,5,2.5,5.5,3,2,3,5.5,4,3,4,5.5,4,3.5,1.5],
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            showInLegend: false,
            fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: So the idea is that I stack the confidence intervals on top of each other, and then draw the prediction line on top of everything else?